# Stunnel for Elasticchache Redis(cluster mode enabled)

Tags: amazon-web-services, redis-cluster, stunnel

I have spin up Elasticcache Redis cluster mode enabled cluster on AWS. I am having 3 master shards and 1 replica for each(total 3 replicas).  I have turn on in-transit encryption. For this I have installed stunnel on my EC2 instance and my config file looks like. 3001 is my cluster port

[redis-cli]
   client = yes
   accept = 127.0.0.1:3001
   connect = master1_url:3001
[redis-cli1]
   client = yes
   accept = 127.0.0.1:3002
   connect = replica1_url.com:3001
[redis-cli2]
   client = yes
   accept = 127.0.0.1:3003
   connect = master2_url:3001
[redis-cli3]
   client = yes
   accept = 127.0.0.1:3004
   connect = replica2_url.com:3001
[redis-cli4]
   client = yes
   accept = 127.0.0.1:3005
   connect = master3_url:3001
[redis-cli3]
   client = yes
   accept = 127.0.0.1:3006
   connect = replica3_url.com:3001
   ----------------------------------------------
sudo netstat -tulnp | grep -i stunnel

tcp        0      0 127.0.0.1:3001          0.0.0.0:*               LISTEN      32272/stunnel
tcp        0      0 127.0.0.1:3002          0.0.0.0:*               LISTEN      32272/stunnel
tcp        0      0 127.0.0.1:3003          0.0.0.0:*               LISTEN      32272/stunnel
tcp        0      0 127.0.0.1:3004          0.0.0.0:*               LISTEN      32272/stunnel
tcp        0      0 127.0.0.1:3005          0.0.0.0:*               LISTEN      32272/stunnel
tcp        0      0 127.0.0.1:3006          0.0.0.0:*               LISTEN      32272/stunnel

When I connect using localhost (src/redis-cli -c -h localhost -p 3001)my connection is successful. But when I hit "get key" it stuck with following
localhost:3001> get key
-> Redirected to slot [12539] located at master3_url:3001

If I change the cluster to single shard and single replica all works fine. What setting I am missing when using multi shards cluster. My Ec2 instance is open to accept connection on all ports. Redis Cluster is open to accept connection from Ec2 instance on all ports.

This is my first question on stackoverflow :)